# Launch another activity with cardview details

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to throw Launch another activity with cardview details

[image]

this tutorial
http://androidbash.com/connecting-android-app-to-a-database-using-php-and-mysql/

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<Movie> movies;

public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.movieName.setText(movies.get(position).getMovieName());
    holder.movieGenre.setText(movies.get(position).getMovieGenre());
    Glide.with(context).load(movies.get(position).getImageLink()).into(holder.imageView);
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}

public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView movieName;
    public TextView movieGenre;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        movieName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.moviename);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        movieGenre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        showPopupMenu(v,position);
    }
}

private void showPopupMenu(View view, int poaition) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuClickListener(poaition));
    popup.show();
}


class MenuClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    Integer pos;
    public MenuClickListener(int pos) {
        this.pos=pos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_favourite:
                Toast.makeText(context, movies.get(pos).getMovieName()+" is added to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_watch:
                Toast.makeText(context, movies.get(pos).getMovieName()+" is added to watchlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_book:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Booked Ticket for "+movies.get(pos).getMovieName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;



            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can put values to Bundle and put this Bundle to intent when starting a new Activity. 
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putExtra(KEY, VALUE);
KEY is a String, VALUE - can be one of allowed types for Bundle (String in your case)
You can make your class Movie serializable (implement a marker interface Serializable) and put it into the bundle. Then in activitie's onCreate you can take it using a specified KEY

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. You should add some more description in your question, not just "this tutorial" with the link and code.

Answer (score 0):

Must read: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

When you click on a card take the data bound to this card and put it to the intent:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    showPopupMenu(v,position);

    Movie movie = movies.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MovieActivity.class);
    intent.putExtraSerializable(MOVIE_KEY, movie);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

To make this work adjust your Movie class:

```
class Movie implements Serializable {// your fields and methods}
```

Then in MovieActivity onCreate:

```
Movie movie = (Movie) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(MOVIE_KEY);
```

Using this instance you can populate your view with a data.